# File-encoding issues with \lstinputlisting

Tags: xetex, listings, input-encodings, matlab

Matlab save `.m` file with `ANSI` encoding.
I have a sample `.m` file, and want import it into LaTeX with `UTF-8` encoding.
How to convert `ANSI` file encoding to `UTF-8` and input it, without changing the original file?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings} 

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[language=Matlab]{sample.m}  % <- how to convert encoding?

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about opening up the `.m` file in your editor, changing the encoding to UTF8 and live happily every after?

Comment: Why do you need it in utf8? Does your code not compile? If so, please provide an MWE. Have you tried `\lstset{inputencoding=utf8}`?

Comment: Dear Werner, I say, I can not change `.m` encoding, because when I open it with Matlab for compiling, Matlab change it to `ANSI` again.

Comment: Oarfish, because I have some comment with non-English language! and I want to show them in Latex, but it will be happen if `.m` file have saved with `UTF-8` encoding.

Comment: Put `feature('DefaultCharacterSet', 'UTF8')` on top of your .m file or change your `startup.m` file. But still you don't need to do anything with your .m file. You can use `matlab-prettifier` package from our user Jubobs, see here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75116/3235

Comment: You may be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution with a tiny trick, but temporarily!

I define some command in my latex such: `\newcommand{\prb}{\rl{تابع احتمال}}`, and in my `.m` file, I use the command `\prb` instead of unicode characters: `تابع احتمال`. 
So, the `.m` file, just consist of ASCI characters. Latex then, execute the command and view `تابع احتمال` in the PDF and work fine!